# File copy only x file extension

Tags: c#, file

I have a working method which copies my files, but I want to add a extra function to it. 
I want to copy only these file extensions:`*.mp4`, `*.LRV` and `*.THM`.

You can see below that there are 2 methodes and a if.. so there are 3 methodes(did not copy everything of the first methode because it issn't relevant).

Some other guy told me that i need to add:
var extensions = new[] { ".MP4", ".LRV", ".THM" };
var files1 = Directory.GetFiles(GoPro1).Where(file => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(file).Extension));
To the first methode.. but this issn't right i get the next error:"Cannot convert from 'String[]'to'String'"

I think i need to add a loop in the methode: copyall. But i don't know what kind of loop i must make. can someone please help me out with this problem?

```
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
  {
  Locatie = dlg.SelectedPath;
  var extensions = new[] { ".MP4", ".LRV", ".THM" };
  var files1 = Directory.GetFiles(GoPro1).Where(file => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(file).Extension));   
  Copy1(files1, Locatie + @"\" + "GoPro1");
  }

public void Copy1(string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory){

    DirectoryInfo diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
    DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);
    //Gets size of all files present in source folder.
    GetSize(diSource, diTarget);
    maxbytes = maxbytes / 1024;

    progressBar1.Maximum = maxbytes;
    CopyAll(diSource, diTarget);
}
    public void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {

        if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
        }
        foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
        {

            fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);

            total += (int)fi.Length;

            copied += (int)fi.Length;
            copied /= 1024;
            progressBar1.Step = copied;

            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            label1.Text = (total / 1048576).ToString() + "MB van de " + (maxbytes / 1024).ToString() + "MB gekopieërd";

            label1.Refresh();
        }
        foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir = target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
            CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Het kopieren is klaar!");
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `new FileInfo(file).Extension` i would use the less expensive `Path.GetExtension(file)`

Comment: your filter should be within the `CopyAll` procedure.

Comment: [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) accepts wildcards. Pass the extension as a pattern (eg *.mp4") instead of iterating over all files. Additionally, you are passing an array of file names to a method expecting a folder name. Or you can use the OpenFileDialog to select multiple files with specific extensions in a single call

Comment: You **define** that `Copy1` with two "directory" params, but **call** it with a list of files and a directory - there's the problem.

Comment: @ Hans Kesting I understand that, but how can i fix this problem?

Comment: @user3637645 It sounds like  you have trouble passing an array of strings as a parameter to a function. This is a fundamental concept. SO's QA format is not the proper place for an introductory language tutorial

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it!

In the last methode: Copyall:
foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles("*.MP4"))
                {

```
                fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);

                total += (int)fi.Length;

                copied += (int)fi.Length;
                copied /= 1024;
                progressBar1.Step = copied;

                progressBar1.PerformStep();
                label1.Text = (total / 1048576).ToString() + "MB van de " + (maxbytes / 1024).ToString() + "MB gekopieërd";

                label1.Refresh();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var files1 = Directory.GetFiles(GoPro1).Where(file => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file));   
foreach (file in files1)     
     File.Copy(file, Locatie + @"\" + "GoPro1");
```

or:

```
var files1 = New DirectoryInfo(GoPro1).EnumerateFiles.Where(file => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file));   
Copy1(files, Locatie + @"\" + "GoPro1\")
```

And the `Copy` method:

```
public void Copy1(IEnumerble<FileInfo> files, string targetDirectory)
{
    maxbytes = files.Sum(x => x.Lenght) / 1024;

    progressBar1.Maximum = maxbytes;        

    foreach(file in files)
    {
       file.Copy(targetDirectory + file.Name)
       ... report progress to ProgressBar
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of iterating over all files, you can do a `Directory.GetFiles(somePath,"*.ext")`

Comment: @user3637645 What errors? Your code has multiple issues, trying to pass an array as a string is only one of them